# Execute a function with a new stack passed in a Linux Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel-module

My  Kernel Module takes as input with `ioctl` a function pointer and a stack size and should create a child process that execute that function with a newly allocated stack of that size. The behaviour is similar to [clone()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)

The function is defined in user space so it must be executed again in user space and it must share the same parent process address space .

I know the correct way to create a new process inside a Kernel Module is to use  `kthread_create` but I need to execute the function in user mode.
I do not see how the [user mode helper API](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kmod.c#L616) can came in handy.

Is it possible to initialize a `struct kernel_struct` specifying that function and stack size as well as copying the address space of the parent process ?

Comment: `clone()` is implemented as return to user from syscall with different states. (return value is different for parent and child) Glibc's part of `pthread_create`  will call new function according to the value. And your module can change any user register, including SP.  Or edit return address to another value.

Comment: @osgx thanks but I am not uderstanding, are you suggesting to copy the current task_struct and modify the user stack pointer and return address?

Comment: mrlin, do you want to create new thread or to do some function without creating new thread?

Comment: I need to implement coroutine so to do a function with a new stack , not necessarily a new thread .But a function with a new stack and the same address space of the current process is a thread or not?

Comment: Thread is the thing which is scheduled, and which has its own set of registers (eip, eax, ebx...esp...). Normal threads (pthread) are scheduled by OS kernel; and coroutines are scheduled in userspace (and not visible by kernel). Address spaces are shared between threads in both cases. When pthread starts new normal thread, it uses clone() syscall and for some return values calls new user function. Why you need to execute function in userspace from kernel? Why it can't use the stack of current thread? (If your function is short and there is space in stack, you may use it, fixing back on return)

Comment: You are right : I need to implement coroutine with kernel support and I want to associate to each coroutine a struct task_struct , so that the coroutine can be activated with wake_up_process and preempted with set_task_state.  The clone() at some point must allocate the task_struct so I was wondering if it is possible to do something similar to the clone and setting in the kernel module in the task_struct the user stack pointer to a new stack and the user instruction pointer to that function.The new stack is required by the API I need to implement : createFiber(function pointer, stack size).

Comment: Kernel can't create coroutine or start it: coroutines are managed in user-space. In your implementation of user-space coroutines (which do you use?) you may add some interface to interact with the kernel. "I want to associate to each coroutine a struct task_struct" - but if you make something which has separate task_struct - this is not coroutines (green thread - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads), this is real thread, scheduled by kernel.

Comment: OK thank you I was confusing coroutine with green thread. Suppose I need to implement green thread, is it possible  to set up the task_struct as said before? . In any case I could somehow prevent the kernel from preempting one green thread for another without the explicit call to switch_to_fiber.

Comment: I understand coroutine as green thread (managed in user-space; all green threads and all coroutines shares same task_struct). If you want fibers to be more like real os threads, you should check how `clone` is implemented in kernel. What is switch_to_fiber? Can you expand the question text with more details of required "fiber" system (may be link to your course or task or to something similar)?